# How to create horizontal carousel in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Goal:** To create a carousel effect when switching between items laid out in a list. Consider the following HTML structure:

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="gallery">
    <li class="slide">
      <!-- Some content -->
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <!-- Some content -->
    </li>
    <!-- Some more items -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Initially, the list `gallery` should be centered inside the `container`, with each list item `slide` stacked on top of each other. After populating the `slide`s with relevant data, the first `slide` should be made active, while the second `slide` be scaled a bit smaller and less opaque (*among other styling that shows that this slide is not active, but in queue*). All the other `slides` should be hidden.

Now, clicking on any item (`slide`) - except for the active one - should trigger the carousel effect, which looks similar to [this implementation by GreenSock](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/LYRwgPo) (The difference is that, first their implementation is dependent on *scrolling* through mouse-wheel, whereas, I want the effect to take place on *clicking* an item. Also, their implementation requires the use of third-party library [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/) and [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/), but I do not want to use either of them - only plain DOM manipulation. Additionally, they have *infinite scroll* but I do *not* want to circle back to the other end when list is finished in either end.)

Answer (score 0):

To create a 3-item carousel effect, we define five possible states for our slide:

- `lhidden` (hidden on the leftmost side)
- `lqueue` (in queue on the left side)
- `active` (the currently active slide)
- `rqueue` (in queue on the right side)
- `rhidden` (hidden on the rightmost side)

The styling for these five states makes use of CSS `opacity`, `z-index`, and `transform` properties.

```css
.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(0px) scale(1);
}

.slide.lqueue {
  opacity: 0.64;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-100%) scale(0.64);
}

.slide.rqueue {
  opacity: 0.64;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(100%) scale(0.64);
}

.slide.lhidden {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: auto;
  transform: translate(-160%) scale(0);
}

.slide.rhidden {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: auto;
  transform: translate(160%) scale(0);
}
```

To place the list `gallery` in center of the `container`, we use `flex` display on `container` and set its `align-center` and `justify-content` to `center`. Then, to make so that each item in the list is stacked on top of each other in the same place, we set `relative` position on the list, and `absolute` position on each item, with `top` margin equal to `0`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

..gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px; /* Can be anything */
  height: 650px; /* Can be anything */
  list-style: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

In the JavaScript, we iterate over each `slide` and set add `rhidden` to their class list. After which, we manually set the first slide to have `active` and the second slide to have `rqueue` class respectively. Then, we attach an event listener to the `click` event on each slide, passing its `index` as argument, so that we can manipulate its immediate siblings to achieve the carousel effect.

```js
function initializeCarousel(){
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
    const slide = slides[index];
    slide.classList.add("rhidden");
    slide.addEventListener("click", () => {
      activateCarousel(index);
    });
  }
  slides[0].classList = "slide active";
  slides[1].classList = "slide rqueue";
}
```

We can only click on three types of slides *since we cannot click on hidden ones*:

- `active`
- `lqueue`
- `rqueue`

If we clicked on `active` slide, we need to do nothing and simply `return`.

If we clicked on either `lqueue` or `rqueue` slide, we set itself to be `active`, and make its surrounding siblings have queue and hidden states based on its index difference from the clicked slide.

```js
 function activateCarousel(index) {
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  const slide = slides[index];

  if (slide.classList.contains("active")) {
    return;
  }

  slide.classList = "slide active";

  if (slides[index - 2] != undefined) {
    slides[index - 2].classList = "slide lhidden";
  }
  if (slides[index - 1] != undefined) {
    slides[index - 1].classList = "slide lqueue";
  }
  if (slides[index + 1] != undefined) {
    slides[index + 1].classList = "slide rqueue";
  }
  if (slides[index + 2] != undefined) {
    slides[index + 2].classList = "slide rhidden";
  }
}
```

A complete implementation should look like the following snippet.

```js
function activateCarousel(index) {
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  const slide = slides[index];

  if (slide.classList.contains("active")) {
    return;
  }

  slide.classList = "slide active";

  if (slides[index - 2] != undefined) {
    slides[index - 2].classList = "slide lhidden";
  }
  if (slides[index - 1] != undefined) {
    slides[index - 1].classList = "slide lqueue";
  }
  if (slides[index + 1] != undefined) {
    slides[index + 1].classList = "slide rqueue";
  }
  if (slides[index + 2] != undefined) {
    slides[index + 2].classList = "slide rhidden";
  }
}

function initializeCarousel() {
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
    const slide = slides[index];
    slide.classList.add("rhidden");
    slide.addEventListener("click", () => {
      activateCarousel(index);
    });
  }
  slides[0].classList = "slide active";
  slides[1].classList = "slide rqueue";
}

initializeCarousel();
```

```css
/* Root structure */

:root {
  --color-primary: #1a1a1d;
  --color-secondary: #955d80;
  --color-tertiary: #d3b6bf;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ce0240, #a80135);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Gallery list layout */

.gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 650px;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Individual item a.k.a "slide" structure */

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffe9e3, #ffe9e3);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* Slide states */

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(0px) scale(1);
}

.slide.lqueue {
  opacity: 0.64;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-100%) scale(0.64);
}

.slide.rqueue {
  opacity: 0.64;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(100%) scale(0.64);
}

.slide.lhidden {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: auto;
  transform: translate(-160%) scale(0);
}

.slide.rhidden {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: auto;
  transform: translate(160%) scale(0);
}

.slide.lqueue *,
.slide.rqueue *,
.slide.lhidden *,
.slide.rhidden * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slide.lqueue *::selection,
.slide.rqueue *::selection,
.slide.lhidden *::selection,
.slide.rhidden *::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Slide specifics */

.slide--picture {
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
  object-position: top;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 60px #ce0240;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slide--name,
.slide--description {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slide--name {
  color: var(--color-primary);
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.slide--description {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <ul class="gallery">
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/l0TNFUosa_avatar-Ex0lN8A5U.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Puff Johnson</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">NCAA Basketball - North Carolina Tar Heels</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/JbSCP9pbj_avatar-A3Pby19td.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Maddie Poppe</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">American Idol Season 16 Winner</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/Sa_09kTuP_avatar-76TOucMti.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Justin Roberts</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Ring Announcer &amp; MC - AEW</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/t8EJJ9Ef4M_avatar-5xB9jXzKl.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Brodie That Dood</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Viral Star - Brodie The Goldendoodle</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/IPFAWngd3_avatar-_XExw5Daa.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Tony Vitello</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Tennessee Baseball Coach</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/hl_Vh7TFN_avatar-Y12cyyBbB.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Omar Narvaez</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">MLB - Milwaukee Brewers</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/1xY4Ue6wb_avatar-aR2of-zCB.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Jordan Schlansky</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Associate Producer - The Conan O'Brien Show</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/Zs7_MjEtl_93Kxr22tk.png?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Colin Mochrie</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Comedian - Whose Line is it Anyway?</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/GrFxbkTTT_PBhuEqlck.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Tommy Chong</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Comedian - Musician - Actor - Writer</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/QQ-agNUb8_27456_001_002_0073_R.JPG?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">James Murray</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">TruTV - Impractical Jokers</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/gxtdQlFH2_avatar-snpKtIVyV.png?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Fortune Feimster</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Actress - Comedian</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/IH6BNRNN1_5F746EBF-BB49-43F6-9EC7-51B4FF831859.jpeg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Andrew Dice Clay</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Comedian</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/X85ZZzwEE_IMG_09552.JPG?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Anthony Anderson</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Actor - Black-ish</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/MdckbEzZy_35105081995_5d36db665a_k.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Fiona the Hippo</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">Animals - Cincinnati Zoo</p>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <img class="slide--picture" src="https://d31wcbk3iidrjq.cloudfront.net/8VF6SrNzw_avatar-jowRSkmuT.jpg?h=320&amp;w=300&amp;q=100" alt="Slide picture">
      <h2 class="slide--name">Susie Essman</h2>
      <p class="slide--description">HBO - Curb Your Enthusiasm</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</main>
```